# NSPredicate query for relation ship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have User and Mobile two entities. User have relation name numbers with Mobile.
here is my code

```
+(void)getUserPhoneNumber:(NSString*)searchString{
NSLog(@"search string is %@",searchString); // e.g. 8
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataManager sharedManager]managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([User class])];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for (User * objUser in array) {
    NSArray *arrayNumber = [(NSSet *)[objUser.numbers valueForKey:@"number"]allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrayNumber);
  //  NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@",searchString];
   NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@",searchString];
    NSArray *filtered = [arrayNumber filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    if (filtered.count>0) {
        NSLog(@"SEARCHED MOBILE NUMBER USER NAME  ----> %@",objUser.fullname);
        NSLog(@"SEARCH PHONE NUMBER IS----> %@",[[filtered objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"number"]);
        return;
    }
}
}
```

I want to fetch numbers while typing on textfield e.g. 8 . It should return with first name and mobile number.
User have attribute name firstname.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, You are creating NSSet of array which only contains only phone number of users so using this array you can not filter number whose name matches with your search string.

If you want to search contact based on search string which contained in name or/and phone number so you can apply following predicate to you requested array.

```
NSArray * filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ContactName contains[c] %@ OR number contains[cd] %@",searchText,searchText]];
```

Here, ContactName is field name for your contactName and number is for your phonenumber field. filtered is your final result array.

OR you can apply this predicate to your NSFetchRequest request so It will deduct your one step which filters array. This will give you direct filtered array.

Hope this might help you.